# why this code didn't work(send list as argument)?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

the code compiled without errors, but when it executed it didn't show correct result. is the problem here related with pointers? especially sending list as argument.
who can help me, I'm very confused, Thanks...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int Element;

typedef struct cell{
    Element val;
    struct cell* next;
} cell ;

typedef struct List{
    cell *first;
}List;

void add(List *l, Element e)
{

    List* a=l;
    cell*nve=(cell*)malloc(sizeof(cell));
    nve->val=e;
    nve->next=NULL;
    if(a->first==NULL)
    {
        l->first->val=nve;
    }
    else
    {
        while(a->first!=NULL)
        {
            a->first=a->first->next;
        }
        a->first->next=nve;
    }
}
void display(List *l){
    List *a=l;
     while(a->first!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\n",a->first->val);
            a->first=a->first->next;
        }
}

int main()
{
    List *x=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    add(x,15);
    add(x,16);
    display(x);

}
 ``
```

Comment: Saying it doesn't work helps with nothing. Your logic seems flawed in `add()`. Plus, take care of deallocating of memory you allocate. Better to use gdb.

Comment: also philosophy helps with nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell {
    int val;
    struct cell *next;
} cell;

typedef struct List {
    cell *first;
} List;

void add(List *l, int e) {
    cell *nve = (cell *) malloc(sizeof(cell));
    nve->val = e;
    nve->next = NULL;
    cell *ptr = l->first;
    if (l->first == NULL) {
        l->first = nve;
    } else {
        while (ptr->next != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = nve;
    }
}

void display(List *l) {
    cell *ptr = l->first;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    List *l = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));
    l->first = NULL;
    add(l, 15);
    add(l, 16);
    add(l, 17);
    display(l);
}
```

Comment: i hope you understood where u did ur mistakes :)

Comment: yeah i understood what you write perfectly.. thank you again...working with a pointer to cell it was a perfect choice